# HTML link to trigger certain jQuery tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

After what seems like a very long time trying to find a solution, I thought it's about time to ask the experts.

I have implemented jQuery tabs to my site, however as well as selecting a tab to show the content, I would also like to be able to show the different tabs content if you click on a standard html link elsewhere on the page.

The page can be seen here http://www.luxury-spa-breaks.com/spa-deals-TEST.html and the html links in question are those down the left hand side (e.g. the user can either select the tab they want or select a region from the left hand side, which would then display that regions tab content).

This is the js I currently have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 //When page loads...
 $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
 $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
 $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

 //On Click Event
 $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
  $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
  $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
  $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content

  var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
  $(activeTab).fadeIn(2000); //Fade in the active ID content
  return false;
 });
});
```

You're help is massively appreciated!

Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to add the same functionality is to add the `tabs` class to the lefthand sidebar, or alternatively, add a selector that selects the sidebar menu to the selector for the tabs.

At this point I would suggest swapping out the code you have there for the one which I rewrote for another Stack Overflow question. It's more efficient and slightly cleaner by conforming to best practises.

```
var tabContents = $(".tab_content").hide(),
    tabs = $("ul.tabs li, .anynavbar ul li"); // Second selector to match left hand sidebar

tabs.first().addClass("active").show();
tabContents.first().show();

tabs.click(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        activeTab = $this.find('a').attr('href');

    if(!$this.hasClass('active') && activeTab.length > 1 && activeTab.indexOf('#') === 0){
        $this.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        tabContents.hide().filter(activeTab).fadeIn();
    }

    return false;
});
```

By doing either of the above, we can add the event handlers necessary to cause the tabs to change.

I've also edited the code to add in a simple check for valid `href` values for use with your HTML, where some of the anchors lack the correct corresponding `href` values to activate the correct tabs. Also, looking at the code you're using right now, you've missed out a `});` at the end for the `document.ready` handler, which is why the code isn't working.

Comment: Hi Yi Jang,
Thanks for the above... I copied the code exactly as above to replace the jquery tabs code that already existed and it never worked.

Each of the tabbed content areas was listed one under the other, instead of being hidden until click.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
THanks again!

Comment: @user Did you include it in the `document.ready` event handler?

Comment: @user Also, all of the links on the sidebar except for the first two "South East" and "South West" have valid `href` values needed for this to work - did you check that too?

Comment: Yep, it is included in the document.ready event handler and as you'll see all tabbed content is loaded below in a list, instead of being hidden.

Comment: Also, the 'South East' and 'South West' links in the side bar were just given hrefs while i was trying to get it to work (which it didn't!).

Comment: @user You didn't close the `document.ready` event handler properly - you've missed the `});` there

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much Yi Jiang. One last thing (I promise!) - when a tab is selected, the tab looks like it's part of the below container, however when the page initially loads the default tab (South East) has a border under the tab and therefore doesn't look like the tab is part of the container.

You've been brilliant, thank you - the longer you look at things, your mind starts to stop!!

Comment: @user You can simply add the `active` class to the first tab for it to get the active tab style

Comment: Hi Yi Jiang. A few weeks ago you helped me with a js issue, which you fixed for me... I've just come back to looking at the site and have noticed that once the code is switched over from a test url to the site, the tabs do not work correctly in IE - just wondering whether this could've been anything to do with the new code you wrote? 
Test url (where the rounded tabs works fine) - http://www.luxury-spa-breaks.com/spa-deals-TEST.html 
Actual URL where the tabs do not display correctly - http://www.luxury-spa-breaks.com/spas/hotel-verta/treatments Any help would be appreciated! Andy

Comment: @YiJiang can this be used on a link within text? so instead of li siblings, <a href="#tab3">Next Property</a>