# Linking to a particular (hidden) tab from the current page and other pages using anchors in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, tabs, hidden, visible

I've examined multiple answers on this site but they haven't been able to solve my problem for whatever reason ([how to select a particular tab from other page using anchor tag in JQuery..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250426/how-to-select-a-particular-tab-from-other-page-using-anchor-tag-in-jquery)). I am only testing this on my local computer so I'm not sure if that would have an impact.

I want to link to each tab from the current page as well as from other pages. Right now I am able to click each tab and it works perfectly and the site URL changes (#tab1, #tab2 etc).

However, for example, if I click the Tab 1 Link (not the actual tab, but a link on the page that is targeted at tab 1) while Tab 2 is visible, nothing happens but the URL changes to /site.html#tab1. However, if I click the Tab 1 link while Tab 1 is visible, it successfully brings me to Tab 1. Something is going wrong because the tabs are hidden - links only work for the tab that is currently visible. I figure if I can at least get it working within the page, I can get it working from links outside the page as well.

Basically, I want to be able to send someone a link to `/site.html#tab3` and have it go to that tab.

My code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

      //Default Action
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

    //On Click Event
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
        return;
    });
});
```

And:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var tabId = window.location.hash; // will look something like "#h-02"
    $(tabId).click(); // after you've bound your click listener
});
```

And the tabs:

```
 <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="#tab1">Ex 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Ex 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">Ex 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab4">Ex 4</a></li>
```

And an example tab content & a link on the page to the tab:

```
//tab content
<div class="tab_container">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
          <h2>Ex 1</h2>

//Link to Tab 1 from right menu
<ul><li>
<a href="#tab1">Click here to go to tab 1</a></li></ul>
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this:

Do this when your page loads (when dom is ready)

```
var tabId = location.hash; // will look something like "#h-02"
```

check for the hash

```
 if(tabId){
   $(tabId).show(); // this will fired only when url get hash
   $(tabId).siblings().hide(); // this will show only targeted tab 
                               // others get hidden
 }
```

what this will do when you get a url like this `site.html#tab1`

`variable tabId` will have the value `#tab1`

then condition in if code block will show the targeted tab

Comment: This worked in combination with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177323/html-link-to-trigger-certain-jqu‌​ery-tabs

Comment: I should clarify that your solution allowed me to link from OTHER pages to a specific tab - which is great. But I do have an issue in general with clicking a link instead of the tab directly:  If I click a link on my menu, it successfully changes to the right tab content. However - when I click a tab, the tab "pops out" while the others stay smaller. When I click a link on the menu to the tab, nothing changes...whatever tab I had last clicked directly on remains "popping out".

Answer (score 1):

Add a common class to your tab links. When you click the link you can trigger a click on the corresponding tab.

HTML

```
<a href="#tab1" class="tab-link">Click here to go to tab 1</a>
```

JS

```
$('.tab-link').click(function(){
    $('ul.tabs li a[href="'+this.href+'"]').parent().click();

});
```

Comment: This didn't work for me for whatever reason but it did lead me to this: [linkhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177323/html-link-to-trigger-certain-jquery-tabs . And this did work - kind of. If I click a link on my menu, it successfully changes to the right tab content.

However - when I click a tab, the tab "pops out" while the others stay smaller. When I click a link on the menu to the tab, nothing changes...whatever tab I had last clicked directly on remains "popping out".