# How to Change Anchor Location

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, position, anchor

I have a bunch of anchors in my site since I'm using jquery tabs and linking to them. However, I want to change where the anchor focuses my screen when I click the link. I don't really care where it focuses as long as it is much higher than it is now instead of directly on top of the anchor. I need to do this without using something that would disrupt the rest of the site since there is content all around the anchor.

The anchor is sitting in here (tab1 is the anchor):

```
<div class="tab_container">
<div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
```

Thanks!

Comment: But tab1 isn't an anchor, it's a div. What do you mean by "focuses my screen"? Are you actually talking about setting the scroll position of the page? ("Focus" refers to which control is currently responding to keyboard input.)

Comment: when you click the link is it focussing on the screen rather than on the tab content?

Comment: Nope, the problem is it is focusing exactly where it should be - directly on top of the tab content. But I want it to focus a little higher if possible. 

My previous question (that I got resolved :) ) actually shows the rest of the code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13560607/linking-to-a-particular-hidden-tab-from-the-current-page-and-other-pages-using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function () { 
    $('a[href^="#"]').click(function(e){        
        e.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').scrollTop($(this.hash).offset().top - 50);
    });
});
```

The `a[href^="#"]` selector will apply to all `a` tags with a `href` attribute that starts with a `#`.

If you need to change the how far above the anchor you want the scroll bar to be, modify the `- 50` at the end.

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/92YaQ/1/)

You can also wrap the scrollTop in an `animate` if you want fancy page sliding ;)

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: ($(this.hash).offset().top - 50)}, 500);
```

[Slidey jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/92YaQ/2/)