# Bootstrap jump to specific section tab/list group

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

When coming from external link or typing on the address bar on the external link, I want it to jump to the specific section, but something seems to go wrong.
It just shows the top of the page instead of going straight to the tab.

For instance, I type in 1.1.1.1/page/#aa on a browser to go straight to that specific section with tab open, but it just sits on the top.

Partial code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row centered">
        <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-8 col-xs-9 tab-container">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 tab-menu">
                <div class="list-group">
                    <a href="#aa" class="list-group-item active text-center">
                        <i class="fa fa-fa"></i><br/>Active
                    </a>
                    <a href="#bb" class="list-group-item text-center">
                        <i class="fa fa-fa"></i><br/>Inactive
                    </a>
                    <a href="#cc" class="list-group-item text-center">
                        <i class="fa fa-fa"></i><br/>More
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var navTabs = $('.nav-tabs a');
        var hash = window.location.hash;
        hash && navTabs.filter('[data-value="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');

        navTabs.on('shown', function (e) {
            var newhash = $(e.target).attr('data-value');
            window.location.hash = newhash;
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Hmm.. the tab is hidden and so you might not be able to access it like that

Comment: I see. What needs to be modified in order to access it?

Comment: Have a look here https://css-tricks.com/better-linkable-tabs/

Comment: I was hoping to make minor modification to JS or something to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well I have revised the entire tab function to make it more efficient and avoid repetitive code (DRY). The problem was that adding a simple `.show()` command was not enough since the tabs are split into separate elements: buttons and content divs. Also the divs do not have an ID, but instead are shown through the css class `active` and the buttons correspond with the content through indexing.

### Edit 2

Updated with a hash change detection and fixed the location scrolling.
The hash detection has a jQuery plugin dependency: [jquery-hashchange](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-hashchange)

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

   var tabButtons = 'div.bhoechie-tab-menu>div.list-group>a';
   var tabContent = 'div.bhoechie-tab>div.bhoechie-tab-content';
   var tabElements = $(tabButtons+','+tabContent);

   // switch tab function 
   function switchTab(index) {
      tabElements.removeClass("active"); // remove active class from current/all tabs and buttons
      $(tabContent).eq(index).addClass("active"); // add active class to selected tab
   }

   // button click function
   $(tabButtons).click(function(e) {
     //e.preventDefault();
     var index = $(this).index(); // get index of clicked button
     switchTab(index); // call switch tab function
     $(this).addClass("active"); // add active class to clicked button
   });

   function hashTab() {
      // get URL Hash
      var hash = window.location.hash;
      // check if hash is set and not empty
      if (hash != '') {
         var hashLink = $('a[href="'+ hash +'"]') // find the button that corresponds with the hash
         switchTab(hashLink.index()); // call switch tab function based on HASH index
         hashLink.addClass('active'); // add active class to tab button

         // scroll to tabs container after 10ms delay
         setTimeout(function() {
            $(document).scrollTop( $("#aa").offset().top );
         }, 10);    

         // debugging
         console.log(hash);
         console.log(hashLink); 
         console.log(hashLink.index()); 
         console.log('#aa offset:'+ $("#aa").offset().top );
     }  
   }
   hashTab(); // fire hash tab function

   // detect hash change
   $(window).hashchange( function(){
      // alert( location.hash ); // debug hash change
      hashTab(); // call tab switch function
   })

});

</script>
```

The code is commented but if you have any questions let me know.

P.S you can remove the console logs they are not required.

<del>What about this code?

    $(function() {

       var hash = window.location.hash; // get hash

       if (hash != '' ) { // make sure a hash is set
          //alert(hash); //debugging
          $(hash).show(); // show tab that matches hash 
          // scroll to tab location:
          //$(document).scrollTop( $(hash).offset().top ); // not working?
          location.href = location.hash;
       }
    });

This might need extra code but that's the simplest form. give it a try!</del>

Comment: Thanks. I tried it, but seems to stay on the top still.

Comment: I have edited the code with `location.href = location.hash;` see if that works - taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13560607/linking-to-a-particular-hidden-tab-from-the-current-page-and-other-pages-using

Comment: Hmm, it still just sits on the top.

Comment: strange, it works for me. Is there any CSS that manipulates the tab's position? Try making a live demo or jsfiddle for us to debug

Comment: why not? also I can't find any anchors in the example you sent. Need to see the exact code. And if the tabs are shown with an active class state then the javascript function will have to be modified to work with the tabs function

Comment: you are right. I'll try debugging locally or if you own a server try hosting it online

Comment: Thanks. Did this work on your local machine? It doesn't seem to work still with this script. It just sits on the top. The best I can still do is use the anchor set on the div id, and call 1.1.1.1/page/#aa.